# UserDefaults Decoder Not Decoding

Tags: swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I have the following decoder code. It always executes the catch block. The error I get is as follows:

> This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding

```
if let dataToRetrieve = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "currentPlayerToon") {
    do {
        let returnedPlayerInformation = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: PlayerClass.self, from: dataToRetrieve)
        print("Success")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Here is my save. This always succeeds.

```
do {
    let dataToSave = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: cachedToonToSave, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(dataToSave, forKey: "currentPlayerToon")
    print("saving worked")
} catch {
    print("saving failed")
}
```

And here is the class declaration.

```
class PlayerClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
    
    
    var toonName : String
```

Comment: you should consume the error in the `catch` statement and see what the problem is. Likely you have a typo in one of the property names.

Comment: This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple wants everyone to use NSSecureCoding instead of just NSCoding. You need to change your class to conform to `NSSecureCoding`. Then you pass `true` to the `requiringSecureCoding` parameter when you create the archive.

```
// Change NSCoding to NSSecureCoding
class PlayerClass: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    // The following is needed as well
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return true }

    var toonName : String
    var toonLevel : Float

    // and the rest as you already have it
```

and:

```
let dataToSave = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: cachedToonToSave, requiringSecureCoding: true)
```

With just those changes your code should work.

You will need to resave the updated data in user defaults before you can load it back in.